# Automatically subscribe pages to messenger webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I am working on a messenger platform that uses a messenger webhook to receive messages, and the Graph API to send messages. I currently need to go into my app settings and choose to subscribe pages that I already own.

I am wondering how I can subscribe pages that I don't own to my webhook. Is this possible if I have the Page Access Token? I can build an OAuth2 flow to get the Page Access Token, but I don't see what to do with it once I have it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making a POST call to `/{page-id}/subscribed_apps` endpoint with your Page Access Token.

API reference docs are at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/